# How to handle Xamarin Webview where a link opens a new tab?

Tags: xamarin, webview, tabbing

I'm using a Xamarin Webview to display a website which has buttons with linked pdf files. Browsers will open the pdf file in a new tab but webview doesn't support tabs and just does nothing on click of the button. How can I handle this?

The most preferable solution would be to show the new tab in the same webview, just as if it wouldn't open a new tab. I tried to implement a custom renderer which inherits from android webview, but even there I found no possibility to handle it or to just get the URL where the button redirects to.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

WebView does not support tabs if you want a tabbed browser UI you need to implement it yourself.

1.Setting `SetSupportMultipleWindows` to true

2.Implementing `WebChromeClient` and override it's `OnCreateWindow` method.

```
public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
            }

        }

    }

    public class MyWebChromeClient: WebChromeClient
    {
        public override bool OnCreateWindow(Android.Webkit.WebView view, bool isDialog, bool isUserGesture, Message resultMsg)
        {

            if(!isDialog)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still dont understand what to do in the OnCreateWindow method. I don't need a tabbed UI, I just want to get the URL of the button target so I can inflate it in my webview, is there really no callback for something like that?

Comment: Yes, still nothing happens when I click on the button

Comment: Could you share your sample ?